# Prove That Every Simple Graph Has Two Vertices Of The Same Degree.

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification, pigeonhole-principle

[image: This is What I got for the problem]

This is my solution to the problem

I just need help verifying if my solution is correct or not.

Comment: The number of edges $m$ never comes into play so there is no need to define $m$ in the first line.

Comment: The simple graph with a single vertex has no edges and thus its single vertex has degree zero. It has no other vertex of the same degree because there is no other vertices, and thus the theorem is false in this case. Therefore, the hypothesis needs to include the condition that the graph has **more** than one vertex.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof looks fine. I could probably be simplified a little bit, but it's fine.

In particular, the last paragraph is redundant, and can be fixed by slightly altering the end of the 2nd-to-last:

"...there must be a vertex $A$ of degree 0, and a different vertex $B$ of degree $n-1$. Since there are exactly $n-1$ non-$B$ vertices, and the graph is simple, $B$ must share an edge with every other vertex, including $A$. But that contradicts the fact that $\deg A = 0$."